# MEF metadata dictionary from object

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mef

I would like to manually create exports for composition, but the Export constructor only accepts a dictionary for metadata, while I should directly create it from the metadata object (IMyMetadata).
Isn't there a way to create the dictionary from the object? Something like this:

```
IDictionary<string, object> metadata = AttributedModelServices.GetMetadataDictionary(metadata)
```

where metadata is an IMyMetadata object.

Essentially, my need is that of using an imported IEnumerable> to create new compositions, sort of "forwarding" values to another CompositionBatch.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't there a way to create the
>   dictionary from the object?

Sure, like this:

```
  public static IDictionary<string, object> GetPropertiesDictionary<T>(object o)
  {
     var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
     {
        dictionary[property.Name] = property.GetValue(o,null);
     }
     return dictionary;
  }
```

> Essentially, my need is that of using
>   an imported IEnumerable to create new
>   compositions, sort of "forwarding"
>   values to another CompositionBatch

It sounds like you're trying to implement sort of a ["ExportMany"](http://mef.codeplex.com/workitem/8153) feature, which does not (yet?) exist in MEF.  (It does exist in some other IOC containers, like [lightweight adapters in AutoFac](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/04/lightweight-adaptation-%E2%80%93-coming-soon/)). You may be able to do without such a feature.

I'm going to assume you have exports of some type (`IStuff`) available, but you need to wrap them in adapters so that you can import them as something else (`IAdaptedStuff`). Maybe you could stick to the normal attributed programming model and do something like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IAdaptedStuffUser))]
public class AdaptedStuffUser : IAdaptedStuffUser
{
   [Import] // instead of [ImportMany(typeof(IAdaptedStuff)))]
   public IAdaptedStuffProvider AdaptedStuffProvider { private get; set; }

   public void DoSomething()
   {
      foreach (var adaptedStuff in AdaptedStuffProvider.GetAdaptedStuff())
      {
         ...
      }
   }
}

[Export(typeof(IAdaptedStuffProvider))]
public AdaptedStuffProvider : IAdaptedStuffProvider
{
   [ImportMany]
   public IEnumerable<IStuff> StuffToAdapt { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<IAdaptedStuff> GetAdaptedStuff()
   {
      return StuffToAdapt.Select(x => new Adapter(x));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I already had the solution with reflection, I was searching for a sort of utility method within MEF. Anyway, the 'AdaptedStuffProvider" is a good hint; hence, this is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can import `IEnumerable<IContract, IDictionary<string, object>>` to get the raw metadata dictionary.  It sounds like this would work for you.

Comment: Sorry, could you provide a short example, please?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
[ImportMany]    
IEnumerable<IContract, IDictionary<string, object>> MyContracts { get; set; }
```

Comment: Now I understand, thank you. But I'd prefer having strongly typed interfaces.